# Colorbox doesn't scroll down when the webpage has scrolled?

Tags: jquery, popup, colorbox, magnific-popup, manual-testing

I'm testing a web based application, were it has some colorbox or some other jquery plugins. When i scroll the page, the corresponding colorbox or jquery plugin popup should gets scrolled or it should be stay where it has positioned.

And another is if i currently on the colorbox popup, then the Tab functionality should be on the Current element of the popup.

Anyone clarify my doubts, Please.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

When you scroll the page, the corresponding jquery plugin popup should stay where it has positioned (i.e., when you scroll down the page, page and popup will move/scroll up)

Yes tab functionality should be on the current element of the popup